# How to send form on ASP.NET Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

i have a send post page A like this:

```
<body>
<form name="main" action="testReceiveOrder.aspx" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" id="rqXML" name="rqXML" value="123"/>
</form>
</body>
```

And another page B.cs to get post:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.Params["rqXML"] != null)
                {
                    Response.Write(Request.Params["rqXML"]);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i don't know how to trigger post in page A.cs Page_Load ?

In page A.cs Page_Load i want to get some data and make a xml put into  value then send this form.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
if(!Request.QueryString["rqXML"].IsEmpty() ) {
     // Do something here
}
```

then if there is a value, just do what you need with it.... 
IsPostBack should be used only when you are processing an "action" after Loading it AFTER the first time....

Comment: Hi @Dryadwoods, but how to send from A.cs Page_Load ?

Comment: Read the following link for some tutorials: http://www.itorian.com/2012/07/5-ways-to-send-data-between-aspnet-pages.html

Comment: Was that useful for you?